# Sed substitution for variable length

Tags: bash, sed

I have a .txt file with the date and time stamped between [ ] on each new line, and then other text after the fact. I want to retain only the text after the time stamps and the names, so how would I code this in bash using sed substitution?
The timestamps are of varying character lengths, as are the names.

**So input would be -**

```
[11/26/17, 9:08:01 AM] Sean: sample text sample text
[8/8/18, 10:54:23 AM] Keith: sample sample sample
[3/8/18, 6:40:25 AM] John Doe: more text more text more text
[12/8/18, 12:40:30 AM] Jane Doe: abcd 1234 text text
```

**Desired output:**

```
sample text sample text
sample sample sample
more text more text more text
abcd 1234 text text
```

Comment: please add what you've tried to question, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 2):

***Solution 1st:*** Following `awk` solution may help you on same.

```
awk '{sub(/.*: /,"")} 1'    Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case you want to save output into Input_file itself then following may help you in same.

```
awk '{sub(/.*: /,"")} 1'  Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

***Solution 3rd:*** In case of you want to take backup of Input_file and save output into Input_file itself then following may help you on same.

```
sed -i.bak 's/.*: //'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution with `sed`**

Assuming that your text file is called `sample.txt`, you can do it like this:

```
$ sed 's/.*: //' sample.txt 
sample text sample text
sample sample sample
more text more text more text
abcd 1234 text text
$
```

Or like this:

```
$ cat sample.txt | sed 's/.*: //'
sample text sample text
sample sample sample
more text more text more text
abcd 1234 text text
$
```

**Explanation of the sed command:**

The `sed` command is between single quotes`'` so that its characters are not interpreted as shell special characters, in this case the `*`.

`s/patter_to_substitute/substitute_with_this/` The `s` is the sed substitute command. It substitutes what is matched by the regex in between the first two `/` with what is in between the second and third `/`. So it will substitute what is matched by `.*:` with nothing since there is nothing between the second and third `/`.

`.*:` matches any character (the `.`) zero or more times (the `*`) until a colon followed by a space (the `:`).

Comment: No need of using `cat` with `sed` as `sed` could read the Input_file by itself. See my answer once too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, you are correct there is no need, but I figured that I'd illustrate that it is possible since often one wants to run the input/file though more than one filter or command, like sort or grep. Anjali seems to be starting out with sed, and maybe the shell. It may be useful information for Anjali.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the cut tool? The following command should work:

```
cat <file> | cut -d':' -f2
```